# Mootools DatePicker standalone

Tags: javascript, mootools, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have a problem using the [Mootools DatePicker](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker) .

When i  use the standalone version (no clicks needed to show the datePicker , it show an empty box)

Here is what i have until now :

http://jsfiddle.net/PcHkD/3/

As you can see if you click inside the input the date show's correctly but onLoad it just show an empty box .

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I see you have files a bug on GitHub. Wait for a response. In fact, it's strange, I don't see errors in your code. Maybe the problem is related with **[this other one](https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/issues/78)**?

Comment: I dont think their forum is still that active , anyway will try to find a solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by calling a focus() not pretty but it does the job .

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $('departure').focus();
});
```

I added the solution I'm using now .. if someone wants to improve it you are welcome :

http://jsfiddle.net/PcHkD/12/

I still need to fix the positions between the 2 calendars